# Importing support library appcompat to Maven project

Tags: android, maven

I converted my Android project into Maven project. I have support library called appcompat_v7, which I would like to add into my Maven dependencies.

I read that I should add dependencies to pom.xml

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>android.support</groupId>
  <artifactId>compatibility-v7-appcompat</artifactId>
  <version>19.1.0</version>
  <type>apklib</type>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>android.support</groupId>
  <artifactId>compatibility-v7-appcompat</artifactId>
  <version>19.1.0</version>
  <type>jar</type>
</dependency>
```

Also built jar and apklib by running:

```
mvn install:install-file -Dfile="./com/android/support/appcompat-v7/19.1.0/appcompat-v7-19.1.0.aar"/ -DpomFile="./com/android/support/appcompat-v7/19.1.0/appcompat-v7-19.1.0.pom"/ -Dpackaging="apklib"

mvn install:install-file -Dfile="./com/android/support/appcompat-v7/19.1.0/appcompat-v7-19.1.0.jar"/ -DpomFile="./com/android/support/appcompat-v7/19.1.0/appcompat-v7-19.1.0.pom"/ -Dpackaging="jar"
```

My pom.xml is now following:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>ProjectTest</groupId>
  <artifactId>ProjectTest</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>  
  <dependency>
    <groupId>com.android.support</groupId>
    <artifactId>appcompat-v7</artifactId>
    <version>19.1.0</version>
    <type>apklib</type>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
     <groupId>com.android.support</groupId>
     <artifactId>appcompat-v7</artifactId>
     <version>19.1.0</version>
     <type>jar</type>
  </dependency> 
  <build>
    <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.1</version>
        <configuration>
          <source/>
          <target/>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

I am still having error ''R cannot be resolved to a variable'' after I deleted support libraby appcompat_v7